# Length formula for Lipschitz curve, i.e. ${\rm Length}\ \gamma = \int_a^b|\gamma '(t)| dt $

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-geometry

I want to prove the following problem. But I think I can only
complete the half : We need to prove the part ${\rm Length}\ \gamma
\geq \int_a^b|\gamma '(t)| dt $

**Problem :** If $\gamma :[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is
$L$-Lipschitz map with $\gamma(0)=(0,0,0)$, then we define ${\rm Length}\ \gamma =\sup_{P} \bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^N |\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1} )| \bigg\}$ over all partition $P=\{t_i\}_{i=0}^N$. Then prove that $$ {\rm
Length}\ \gamma =\int_a^b|\gamma '(t)| dt
$$

(This is an exercise in the **book**, What is differential geometry : curves and surfaces - Petrunin and Barrera)

**Proof :**

**Step 1 :** If $\gamma$ is $L$-Lipschitz, then each
component functions $x,\ y,\ z$ of $\gamma$ is $L$-Lispchitz :

\begin{align*}L|s-t|&\geq |\gamma (s)-\gamma (t)| \\&= \sqrt{ (x(s)-x(t))^2 +
(y(s)-y(t))^2 + (z(s)-z(t))^2} \\& \geq | x(s)-x(t) |
\end{align*}

**Step 2 :** By **Rademacher Theorem**, we have
measurable functions $ x',\ y',\ z'$ with a bound $M$.

By **Lusin Theorem** on $[a,b]$, there are continuous functions
$X_\epsilon, \ Y_\epsilon,\ Z_\epsilon$ with a bound $M$ s.t. $x',\
X_\epsilon$ coincides outside some set of measure $< T $ and so does
$Y_\epsilon,\
Z_\epsilon$

**Step 3 :** We define $\alpha = (f,g,h)(t)$ where $$
f(t)=\int_a^t X_\epsilon (s)ds,\ g(t)=\int_a^t Y_\epsilon (s)ds,\
 h(t)=\int_a^t Z_\epsilon (s)ds $$

Hence $\alpha$ is in $C^1$-class i.e., continuous first derivatives, so that we have ${\rm Length}\ \alpha = \int_a^b |\alpha'(t)|\ dt
 $ in the same book (I think I have already proved by using fundamental theorem of calculus, but I think it is still messy)

Furthermore, by **Lusin Theorem**, $$ \bigg|
 \int_a^b |\alpha'(t)| dt -\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|dt\bigg|<2\sqrt{3}M T $$

By **Rademacher Theorem**, $$
|x(t)-f(t)| =\bigg|\int_a^t (x'(s)- X_\epsilon (s)) ds \bigg|<2MT $$

Hence $$|\alpha (t)-\gamma(t)| \leq 2\sqrt{3} MT
$$

$$\bigg||\gamma (t_i)-\gamma (t_{i+1}) | - |\alpha (t_i)-
\alpha (t_{i+1} )| \bigg|  < 4\sqrt{3} MT $$

Assume that given $\epsilon>0$, there is a partition $\{
t_i\}_{i=0}^N$ for $\gamma$ s.t.
$$\bigg|{\rm Length}\ \gamma - \sum_{i=1}^N\ |\gamma
(t_i)-\gamma (t_{i+1}) | \bigg|<\epsilon$$

If $4\sqrt{3}MNT<\epsilon$, then $$ \bigg|{\rm Length}\ \gamma
-\sum_i\ |\alpha (t_i)- \alpha (t_{i+1} )|\bigg|  < 2\epsilon  $$

so that \begin{align*}{\rm Length}\ \gamma &\leq\sum_{i=1}^N \
\bigg|\alpha (t_i)- \alpha (t_{i-1} )\bigg| + 2\epsilon
\\&\leq \int_a^b|\alpha'(t)|dt +2\epsilon \\&\leq
\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|dt +3\epsilon
 \end{align*}

How could we prove the remaining ?

Comment: How is the length of $\gamma$ defined? I guess it is defined as $$ \operatorname{Length}(\gamma)=\sup_{\Pi}\sum_{[t_{i-1},t_i]\in\Pi}\|\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1})\|$$ where the supremum is taken over all partitions $\Pi$ of $[a, b]$, but your input is crucial for clarifying this.

Comment: Yes. I missed that part. The length of $\gamma$ is defined through the formula above you wrote. Since $\gamma $ is Lipschitz, then the limit exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will complete the proof. (If you have another one, I'll be welcome)

If $I_i$ is a disjoint open interval in $[a,b]$ s.t.
$\bigcup_i I_i$ with $\sum_i\ {\rm Length}\ I_i <2T<\epsilon$ covers
the set $K$ s.t. $x',\ X_\epsilon$ (respectively $y',\ Y_\epsilon$
and $z',\ Z_\epsilon$) coincides on the compliment $\widetilde{K}$.

Since $x'=X_\epsilon$ on $\widetilde{K}$, if $[a',b']$ is in
$\widetilde{\bigcup_i I_i}$, then $\gamma |[a',b']$ is a **translation**
of $\alpha |[a',b']$.

Hence since $|\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|dt-\int_a^b|\alpha'(t)|dt|\leq 2\sqrt{3}MT$, then \begin{align*}\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|dt -2\sqrt{3}MT
-\sqrt{3}M\epsilon &\leq {\rm Length}\ \alpha -\sqrt{3}M \epsilon
\\&\leq {\rm Length}\ \alpha|\widetilde{\bigcup_i I_i} \\&= {\rm Length}\
\gamma|\widetilde{\bigcup_i I_i} \\
&\leq {\rm Length}\ \gamma\end{align*} so that we have $\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|dt \leq {\rm Length}\
\gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me refine your argument and also show the opposite direction.

Since $\gamma$ is Lipschitz continuous, it is absolutely continuous and hence the fundamental theorem of calculus holds for $\gamma$, that is, $\gamma'$ is defined a.e. on $[a, b]$, integrable, and satisfies

$$ \forall [c, d] \subseteq [a, b] \ : \quad \int_{c}^{d} \gamma'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \gamma(d) - \gamma(c). $$

(You may already know that this type of statement holds in 1D. The above 3D version is an easy corollary of the 1D counterpart.) So, for any partition $\Pi=\{a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=b\}$ of $[a, b]$,

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \|\gamma(t_i) - \gamma(t_{i-1})\|
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left\| \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} \gamma'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right\|
\leq \int_{a}^{b} \|\gamma'(t)\| \, \mathrm{d}t.
$$

Taking supremum over all possible choices of $\Pi$, we obtain

$$ \operatorname{Length}(\gamma) \leq \int_{a}^{b} \|\gamma'(t)\| \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{1} $$

To show the opposite inequality, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be any two absolutely continuous $\mathbb{R}^3$-valued functions on $[a, b]$. Then by arguing similarly as above, we find that (see the proof below)

$$ \left| \operatorname{Length}(\alpha) - \operatorname{Length}(\beta) \right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} \| \alpha'(t) - \beta'(t) \| \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{2} $$

Moreover, if $\alpha$ is $C^1$, then we have

$$ \operatorname{Length}(\alpha) = \int_{a}^{b} \| \alpha'(t) \| \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{3} $$

Finally, choose a sequence of $C^1$ curves $\gamma_n$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} \| \gamma_n'(t) - \gamma'(t) \| \, \mathrm{d}t \to 0$. Then by the triangle inequality,

\begin{align*}
&\left| \operatorname{Length}(\gamma) - \int_{a}^{b} \|\gamma'(t)\| \, \mathrm{d}t \right| \\
&\qquad\leq \left| \operatorname{Length}(\gamma) - \operatorname{Length}(\gamma_n) \right|
+ \smash[t]{\overbrace{\left| \operatorname{Length}(\gamma_n) - \int_{a}^{b} \|\gamma_n'(t)\| \, \mathrm{d}t \right|}^{=0 \text{ by (3)}}} \\
&\qquad\qquad + \left| \int_{a}^{b} (\|\gamma'(t)\| - \|\gamma_n'(t)\|) \, \mathrm{d}t \right|\\
&\qquad\leq 2\int_{a}^{b} \| \gamma_n'(t) - \gamma'(t) \| \, \mathrm{d}t
\to 0,
\end{align*}

where the last inequality follows from $\text{(2)}$. Therefore the desired claim follows.

(In summary, the two functionals $\alpha' \mapsto \operatorname{Length}(\alpha)$ and $\alpha' \mapsto \int_{a}^{b} \|\alpha'(t)\| \, \mathrm{d}t$ are continuous with respect to the $L^1$-norm of $\alpha'$ and coincide on the dense subset of their domains. So they must agree.)

---

**1)** To show the inequality $(2)$, note that for any curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$ defined on the interval $[a, b]$ and for any partition $\Pi = \{t_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ of $[a, b]$,

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=1}^{n} \| (\alpha(t_i) + \beta(t_i)) - (\alpha(t_{i-1}) + \beta(t_{i-1}) \| \\
&\quad \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \| \alpha(t_i) - \alpha(t_{i-1} \| + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \| \beta(t_i) - \beta(t_{i-1} \| \\
&\quad \leq \operatorname{Length}(\alpha) + \operatorname{Length}(\beta),
\end{align*}

and taking supremum over all possible $\Pi$, we get

$$ \operatorname{Length}(\alpha + \beta) \leq \operatorname{Length}(\alpha) + \operatorname{Length}(\beta) $$

Now assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are absolutely continuous. Then the above inequality gives

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Length}(\alpha) &\leq \operatorname{Length}(\alpha - \beta) + \operatorname{Length}(\beta), \\
\operatorname{Length}(\beta) &\leq \operatorname{Length}(\beta - \alpha) + \operatorname{Length}(\alpha).
\end{align*}

Since all the indicated lengths are finite, we can rearrange the above inequality to obtain the reverse triangle inequality:

$$ \left| \operatorname{Length}(\alpha) - \operatorname{Length}(\beta) \right|
\leq \operatorname{Length}(\alpha - \beta)
\leq \int_{a}^{b} \| \alpha'(t) - \beta'(t) \| \, \mathrm{d}t, $$

where the last inequality has already been proved in the above answer.

Comment: First part is easy and clear. Thank you. But I don't understand the inequality $\cdots \leq 2\int_a^b \|\gamma_n'(t)-\gamma(t)\| dt$

Comment: @HKLee, I added a bit more details.

Comment: I am asking about the second inequality.

Comment: @HKLee, Oh, I see. I forgot to include the norm there. I fixed it now. Anyway, it is the combination of the inequalities $$\left|\operatorname{Length}(\gamma)-\operatorname{Length}(\gamma_n)\right|\leq\int_{a}^{b} \| \gamma_n'(t) - \gamma(t) \| \, \mathrm{d}t$$ and \begin{align*}\left| \int_{a}^{b} (\|\gamma_n'(t)\| - \|\gamma'(t)\|) \, \mathrm{d}t \right| &\leq \int_{a}^{b} \left| \|\gamma_n'(t)\| - \|\gamma'(t)\| \right| \, \mathrm{d}t \\ &\leq \int_{a}^{b} \| \gamma_n'(t) - \gamma(t) \| \, \mathrm{d}t, \end{align*} where in the last line we utilized the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: I don't understand this inequality $|{\rm Length}(\gamma)-{\rm Length}\ (\gamma_n)|\leq \int_a^b \| \gamma_n'(t)-\gamma(t)\| dt$. How could you derive this ?

Comment: @HKLee, Is that because of my typo that the $\int_{a}^{b} \| \gamma_n'(t) - \gamma(t) \| \, \mathrm{d}t$ should be in fact $\int_{a}^{b} \| \gamma_n'(t) - \gamma'(t) \| \, \mathrm{d}t$, or because you don't understand the inequality $(2)$ in my answer? Note that there is a comment regarding how to derive this inequality in my answer, and I now expanded that comment so it now comprises a self-contained proof. Hope this clarifies.